# Cocoapods ignoring the Target's SWIFT_VERSION and sets 3.0 instead

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode9

From what I understand the Swift version used for your pods will be the Swift version specified in your main targets in your project.

My project has SWIFT_VERSION 4.1 set:

[image]

but when the debug or release `xcconfig` is generated, the `SWIFT_VERSION` version is set to 3.0. I can't find the reason why this happens:

[image]

I have a mixed 3.2 and 4.1 swift setup:

[image]

cocoapods: v 1.4.0 (tried 1.5.0 with no luck)
xcode: v9.3 (same on 9.2)

Thanks for any insights.

note: good resource [here](https://www.cerebralgardens.com/blog/entry/2017/10/04/mix-and-match-swift-3-swift-4-libraries-with-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

the value came from one of the pods specs:

`"xcconfig": {
        "SWIFT_VERSION": "3.0"
      },`

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/d0ec5a65e80656c8d78e12ff19f251df879e0bc2/Specs/d/1/8/CocoaLumberjack/3.0.0/CocoaLumberjack.podspec.json#L75